# Migration of virtual machines

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, xen, kvm, qemu

Are there tools for migrating from one virtual machine type to another?  E.g let's say I have some Xen virtual machine and like to make it run under KVM. I know that qeumu has tools which can be used to "migrate" such machines, but how about:

Xen -> Kvm
Kvm -> Xen
Xen -> VMware (server?)

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: There are just 5 tags allowed, I wanted to add maybe-not-programmming-related....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you're looking for is OVF (Open Virtualization Format). It looks like its support in KVM is controversial, but otherwise I think it's been received pretty positively. (Disclaimer: I work for VMware, one of the co-creators of OVF)

Comment: Does that mean I can take e.g my XEn vm and make it into some vmware System?

Comment: Conceptually, that's the idea. I haven't worked with OVF and Xen's VMs. A quick search shows a "Project Kensho" at Citrix that works with OVF. VMware has support for it in a number of places, from a command line utility called "ovftool" to direct support in Virtual Center.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a function migratetouri in libvirt which might help you in the same. But I am not really sure about it.